# 301 redirect with Apache: All paths of URL to a single path

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, apache2, mod-alias

I am migrating a website from one platform to another, and in that process, I'm getting rid of the old domain name.
There is no direct relation between the [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)s on the old and new website, and therefore, I want to redirect all old paths to the new websites' front page: I.e. *olddomain.example/any_path* should redirect to the front page of *newdomain.example*.
I am aware of the SEO consequences of this.

My current solution is to use the [RedirectPermanent](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) directive, so that my `.htaccess` in the domain's root directory contains:

```
RedirectPermanent / https://newdomain.example/
```

How do I achieve that any path on *olddomain.example* (e.g. *olddomain.example/any_path*) is redirected to the front page (and not the corresponding path) of *newdomain.example*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for you. On the old domain, put this code in the `.htaccess` file (this assumes a 301 redirect is used).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.example [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> My current solution is to use the `RedirectPermanent` directive

The `RedirectPermanent` (mod_alias) directive is *prefix* matching so, as you have found, you will be redirected to the "corresponding path" on the newdomain.

However, the complementary mod_alias directive `RedirectMatch` matches using a regex and will allow you to redirect all URLs to the single root URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 / https://newdomain.example/
```

This is marginally preferable to using mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`), unless you are already using mod_rewrite for other redirects.

> I am aware of the SEO consequences of this.

Not just SEO (Google will most probably treat this as a soft-404), but also a usability issue. It would be preferable (less confusing) for the user to redirect to the same URL-path on the new domain and serve a custom 404 - explaining the absence of the old page, with links to the homepage and other key pages on the site and possibly a site-search feature to allow new content to be found.